# matlab make matrix from vectors with gaps

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have two sets of time-series data, indexed by dates in the first columns; values are in the second. Dates are represented in yyyymmdd format (e.g. Pearl Harbor Day is 19411207)  The two time series overlap, but neither is a subset of the other, and even in the overlap, there may be dates missing, and due to the format, there are gaps in the numerical sequence.  Since these dates end up just being integers, I will substitute small numbers below for ease of reading.

I want to turn these two matrices (a 26622x2 and a 38067x2) into a single three-column matrix (38103x3, as it turns out.)

The merge I am after is this:

```
 Index AVal             Index BVal             Index AVal   BVal
   1     2.5               3    6.5             1     2.5
   2     3.4     +         5    8.9   =         2     3.4
   4     5.6               7    9.1             3            6.5
   5     7.8               8    7.1             4     5.6
   7     8.00                                   5     7.8    8.9
                                                7     8.00   9.1
                                                8            7.1
```

In Excel, I would do this with VLookup.  I can imagine an approach in Matlab that uses lots of conditionals, loops and stored indices, but I am wondering if there isn't possibly a very simple set of join/intersect-type commands that would accomplish the same thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you really use tables (which is a new feature of Matlab 2013b) or matrices?

Comment: Are there any repeated dates (within one of the source tables, not overlap)? Your example shows no repeats in either table.

Comment: Daniel - I did mean matrices - I am still on Matlab 2010, and didn't know about the new Tables.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `setdiff` to identify the dates in `B` not in `A`, then concatenate with `NaN`s or some other value for missing values:

```
A = [1 2.5; 2 3.4; 4 5.6; 5 7.8; 7 8.0];
B = [3 6.5; 5 8.9; 7 9.1; 8 7.1];

[BnA,iB] = setdiff(B(:,1),A(:,1));
C = [A NaN(size(A,1),1); BnA NaN(numel(BnA),1) B(iB,2)]
C =
    1.0000    2.5000       NaN
    2.0000    3.4000       NaN
    4.0000    5.6000       NaN
    5.0000    7.8000       NaN
    7.0000    8.0000       NaN
    3.0000       NaN    6.5000
    8.0000       NaN    7.100
```

Then use `intersect` to handle values that are common to both:

```
[AB,iA,iBA] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1));
C(iA,3) = B(iBA,2)
C =
    1.0000    2.5000       NaN
    2.0000    3.4000       NaN
    4.0000    5.6000       NaN
    5.0000    7.8000    8.9000
    7.0000    8.0000    9.1000
    3.0000       NaN    6.5000
    8.0000       NaN    7.1000
```

Then use `sortrows` to sort according to to the first column:

```
C = sortrows(C,1)
C =
    1.0000    2.5000       NaN
    2.0000    3.4000       NaN
    3.0000       NaN    6.5000
    4.0000    5.6000       NaN
    5.0000    7.8000    8.9000
    7.0000    8.0000    9.1000
    8.0000       NaN    7.1000
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. Hopefully the OP is talking about regular arrays and not the new `table`s as Daniel R. pointed out.

Comment: I thought there might be a one-liner lurking out there, but this is only a couple lines and it worked perfectly - thanks!