# Filename matching between two datasets

Tags: matlab, join, merge

I have a list of files loaded in MATLAB with common labels.

```
  label   filename   A   B
   1       xxx       6
   1       xxx       2
   1       xxx       3
   2       yyy       1
   2       yyy       4
   3       zzz       6
   3       zzz       7
```

I have another batch of files the following way:

```
 filename     A      B
   yyy        1
   yyy        4
   aaa        2
   aaa        4
   aaa        6
   aaa        10
   zzz        6
   zzz        7
```

I need to match the filenames in set 1 and set 2 and assign the same labels to set 2 (numbers). The purpose of matching the labels is that the labels in set_1 has the max value in column A for each filename. Now in a similar war I need to find if the max value of each filename in set_2 matches with set_2.

Comment: Sorry, I was so busy to review my answer but I think @gnovice answer desires what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same thing as "VLookUp" in excel. You can use `ismember`:

```
  [finder, indx] = ismember(Set2(:, 1), Set1(:, 2));

%Label will be in the 3rd column of Set2 (pre-allocation is needed):
  Set2(finder, 3) = Set1(indx(finder), 1);
```

Comment: Also refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643364/matlab-make-matrix-from-vectors-with-gaps)

Comment: In my case the set 1 and set 2 do not have the same variables(only few variables are same) and hence I get error while using ismember.

Comment: @DaphneMariaravi They're not supposed to be the same. it is applied to the filename only. What's the error and on what line?

Comment: I am getting an error stating"Error using tabular/ismember (line 45)
A and B must contain the same variables."

Comment: @DaphneMariaravi Provide a sample dataset that represent your data and then I can help you. Based on what you have in your question, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to compare the maximum value associated with a given file between two data sets, you can forego worrying about labels in this case. I'll use the two sample data sets from your question for the example here (assuming these are [tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) of data like [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44209430/52738)):

```
T1 = table([1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3], ...
           {'xxx'; 'xxx'; 'xxx'; 'yyy'; 'yyy'; 'zzz'; 'zzz'}, ...
           [6; 2; 3; 1; 4; 6; 7], ...
           'VariableNames', {'Label', 'Filename', 'A'});
T2 = table({'yyy'; 'yyy'; 'aaa'; 'aaa'; 'aaa'; 'aaa'; 'zzz'; 'zzz'}, ...
           [1; 4; 2; 4; 6; 10; 6; 7], ...
           'VariableNames', {'Filename', 'A'});
```

First, you can use [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to get a list of files common to both tables. Then use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find indices of the common files in each set to use for accumulating the values and finding the maximum with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
commonFiles = intersect(T1.Filename, T2.Filename);

[index, accumIndex] = ismember(T1.Filename, commonFiles);
max1 = accumarray(accumIndex(index), T1.A(index), [], @max);  % Max values for set 1

[index, accumIndex] = ismember(T2.Filename, commonFiles);
max2 = accumarray(accumIndex(index), T2.A(index), [], @max);  % Max values for set 2
```

Now we can visualize the data with a table:

```
T3 = table(commonFiles, max1, max2);

T3 = 

    commonFiles    max1    max2
    ___________    ____    ____

    'yyy'          4       4   
    'zzz'          7       7
```

In this example, the maximum values are the same for each file across the two sets. If you wanted to just focus on the ones that were different, you could do this:

```
index = (max1 ~= max2);  % Index of differing maxima
T3 = table(commonFiles(index), max1(index), max2(index));
```